# set HTTP headers in WebEngine JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

How to pass the HTTP Headers like

"Accept-Language", "Accept", "Accept-Encoding" to WebEngine in JavaFX? i have tried the method as specified in [Setting a cookie using JavaFX's WebEngine/WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385233/setting-a-cookie-using-javafxs-webengine-webview), but it doesn't work. is there any API that is being exposed in Java 8 for achieving this? Pls suggest.

Comment: Your question is possible duplicate, see answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803480/useragent-implement-method-on-javafx-webengine

Comment: Thanks @janih - Still there're no docs or links to specify how to set http headers other than User-Agent. Has that been made possible with JavaFX 8? I browsed through the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) , but couldn't find any relevant methods.

Comment: you are right, it doesn't seem to be possible to set other headers than user agent. However, it might be possible to set the http headers by implementing [a custom protocol handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522343/custom-javafx-webview-protocol-handler)

Comment: Actually the only way i found, was it: https://twitter.com/CodingFabian/status/524942996748652544

Comment: look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917469/how-can-i-work-around-youtube-api-embed-restrictions-like-other-websites?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

Since JDK 8u60 the default locale of the application is automatically added to the "Accept-Language" header as the first option. This may help in some cases although it would of course be better to be able to set all these headers explicitly.