# JavaFx Webview goes to mobile site -(using jdk 7)

Tags: java, webview, javafx, java-7, javafx-webengine

I am trying to create a JavaFX desktop application which consists of an embedded browser.

```
webEngine.load("http://sampleurl");
```

This statment loads the mobile website for some sites and for some others it loads the desktop site. 
Is this because of JavaFX or the implementation of the respective websites?

Morever the view is exactly same as IE. Is it possible to change it to chrome or mozilla?
I am using jdk 7.

Comment: What do you mean be 'the view is exactly same as IE'. Have you tried setting a different user-agent in the JVM? I'm just suggesting, because I haven't tried that with the `WebView`.

Comment: for eg. I tried opening google.com using webView. The html tags that I see in the page source of webView is exactly same as the ones in IE 8 browser which is different from Chrome. Also the look and feel is same as IE8, which again is different from chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an comment an this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803480/useragent-implement-method-on-javafx-webengine)'s answer. You should be able to set a user agent for your Weview with `webEngine.setUserAgent(USER_AGENT_STRING)`.
It seems to need JDK8 though. Indeed the [JavaFX 2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) javadoc doesn't contain it, though the [JavaFX 8 one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) does.

You may be able to fake something like a Windows Chrome Browser with a user agent string like this one:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36`

If you really need to use JDK7, you may be stuck here. Setting the JVM's user agent may be sufficient, but probably it will use an internal user agent.

Comment: well I am stuck with JDK7 for now because JBOSS for JDK8 is not yet out. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @wib How are you using JavaFX, a desktop technology, on a Java EE application server? Those are two totally different use cases in my opinion.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am using javafx to launch an embedded browser which in turn is redirected to a web application(also created by me)

Comment: but shouldn't the javafx project be separated from the servers code? this way you could also use jdk8 for javafx8 and jdk7 for your java ee project.

Comment: agreed. that will allow me to set the user agent but will I be able to detect the user agent in jdk7 on the server?

Comment: If you call `HttpServletRequest request.getHeader("User-Agent");` on the server side, it will detect your client's user agent. That's two different things.